# I am implementing set(MySet) using custom MyNode(Singly linked list). I am having trouble in making union

Tags: java

```
public class MyNode {
    Object element;
    MyNode nextNode;
    public MyNode(Object element) {
        this.element = element;
    }
    public MyNode() {}
}
public class Myset {
    int size = 0;
    MyNode head;
    MyNode tail;
    public void Insert(Object o) {
        MyNode node = new MyNode(o);
        if (tail == null) {
            head = node;
            tail = node;
        } else {
            tail.nextNode = node;
            tail = node;
        }
        size++;
    }
    public Myset Union(Myset a) {
    /*
     * case1 a is empty return currentSet
     * case2 a is non empty 
     *       create a variable temp1=a
     *       check for all members of a whether they are a member of currentSet. Delete those from temp1 which are members of currentSet.
     *       add each element of temp1 to currentSet
     *       return currentSet 
     * 
     */
    }
}
```

So my question is what should i return as `currentSet`?

Comment: Just for clarifying your question, here's a silly answer: you return _the union of the two sets_, or, a set that only has elements common in both `currentSet` and `a`. The algorithm you outlined doesn't quite do that. Are you asking for Java code or for a correct algorithm?

Comment: My question is what would be currentSet? So i am not asking for algorithm but a code would help.

Comment: Just to be clear and hopefully helpful - what I meant with algorithm is what you wrote between `/*` and `*/`: it won't return the Union of two sets. Before getting to the code, I would suggest to get that part right. Here's a suggestion: try to say it in one sentence.

Comment: I think the algorithm is correct

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right - I misread. Do you already have a way to iterate through all the elements of a `MySet`?

Comment: Yes that i can do. See Insert method for example